# Storing pictures on the server and linking them in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Can someone explain me how to store images on a server and then inserting the url's in the database.

All I find on the internet are discussions of which one is better - storing the url or the image itself as a BLOB. I have made it to store them as BLOB, but I don't think it is a good idea and want to store them on the server and just link them in the database.

I am using asp.net web application and have a mssql database. The language is c#.

Comment: If you have a specific programming question, we are happy to help. If you want a tutorial - google for one - that's not what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Do you want to save the picture to the database? you can dynamically load in the links and filename from the database and the server will pull in the image using a standard <img src.. tag

Comment: @Oded, I tried google and all I find are tutorials about storing the images in the database. Then I guess you are right, so instead, I can ask how to store images on the server and link them to the database?

Comment: @CR41G14 no, I want to store them on the server. The database should just contain the information about the picture - like the url, picture name and so on..

Comment: Sure, you can ask that. But you will need to explain exactly what you tried, where you are stuck and post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this article explaining [Storing Uploaded Files in a Database or in the File System with ASP.NET 2.0](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20) along with *advantages* and *disadvantages* of each technique.

Also found a useful link that might help you in this regard: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You must have directory at your server like:

```
~/Uploads/Photos/
```

And in database you can have table:

```
Images { ImageId, PathOriginal, PathMediumSize, Thumb }
```

And data would be like:

```
/Uploads/Photos/myImageNameOriginal.png
```

When you wan't to display it get it's name from database and load on page from Uploads directory.

Comment: Yes, I have these, my question was how to do it - the link above helps me. Thanks again.